# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \exp [ \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2} ] \ dx$

Tags: probability, integration

I have so far $$M(t) = E(e^{tX^2}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \exp \left[ \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ] \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \left [ \frac{-x^2(1-t)}{2\sigma^2} \right ] \ dx$$

I've tried numerous substitutions and playing around but with no luck. There is a hint to use the fact that the integral of any density of a normal dist. is $1$.

Any help please

edit: answer should be $$ M(t) = (1-2\sigma^2 t)^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^2}dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \exp \left[ \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ] \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \left [ \frac{-x^2+2\sigma^2tx^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ] \ dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp \left [ \frac{-1}{2}\frac{x^2-2\sigma^2tx^2}{\sigma^2} \right ] \ dx$$

Let 
$$u^2=\frac{x^2-2\sigma^2tx^2}{\sigma^2}$$
$$u'=2x\frac{1-2\sigma^2t}{\sigma^2}*\frac{\sigma}{2x\sqrt{1-2\sigma^2t}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-2\sigma^2t}}{\sigma}$$

Then I will leave the conclusion to be drawn.